# Edit/Delete a Contact From Phone Contacts with apple default Edit screen

Tags: ios, swift, contacts, addressbook

I want to delete a contact from address book through my app,Can anyone help me.I'm working with addressbook framework.[image]

I wanna be screen like the above with delete contact option,But for me there is no delete option

```
 let addr:ABMultiValue = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(ABPropertyType(kABStringPropertyType)).takeRetainedValue()
    ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(addr,SecondPart as String, kABHomeLabel, nil)

    ABRecordSetValue(newPerson, kABPersonPhoneProperty, addr, nil)


    let picker: ABNewPersonViewController = ABNewPersonViewController()
    picker.displayedPerson = newPerson
    picker.newPersonViewDelegate = self
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(picker, animated: true)
```

when i googling for this problem found [one ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37225374/programmatically-remove-contact-from-adress-book-on-specific-time-in-swift) , but is not suitable.through the link how can i acheive this.

and also tried as like below

```
picker.allowsDeletion = true
```

But for this having error,bcoz there is no member function in ABNewPersonViewController

Can u help me!,thanks in advance

Comment: Check out: [ABAddressBook Category on Github](https://github.com/shrtlist/ABDelete)

Comment: Ya checked out,In that file too there is no edit option in contact detail.

Comment: It has a category implemented, which you need to use in order to be able to delete record using ABAddressBook Framework.

Comment: How can i use this

Comment: Ya i tried With this [link](https://github.com/shrtlist/ABDelete),now the error in init(),bcoz of my project is with swift but this one is objc.o having issue in init method in swift(Using bridging)

Comment: Hey @learnigkid did you manage to show the delete button?